# How do you describe somebody who was judged and found wanting?

Tags: word-choice

"The King judged the man, and the man was found wanting".

Is it correct to say that "the man failed the judgment", or is there a more appropriate phrasing than "pass/fail" when discussing the result of a judgment?

Comment: Depending on how you want to use it you might get away with just: *the adjudged*

Comment: It takes several factors for the King's judgement to be regarded as legitimate. In the absence of those factors, the King's judgement is found wanting by the *innocent man*.

Comment: *weighed in the balance and found wanting* - the handwriting on the wall, Mene, mene tekel upharsin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that a person would [**fall short**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fall+short) or perhaps *found wanting*:

> To fail to attain a specified amount, level, or degree: *an athlete whose skill fell far short of expectations.*
> To prove inadequate: *food supplies fell short*.
> For all *fall short* of the glory of God...

This concept of falling short is extremely old.
In Ancient Egypt, a person upon death would face Isis and Osiris, and the scales of Judgement. On one side was the feather of Maat - what a good person's heart should weigh if they had done little harm during life. On the other, one's heart. Overseen by Anubis, if one had fallen short, and found wanting, the soul would be turned over to Ammut, a crocodile-headed god, the devourer of the dead).

> ... forepart is like that of a crocodile, the middle of her body is like that of a lion, her hind quarters are like those of a hippopotamus.
>
> O my heart of my being!
> Do not rise up against me as witness,
> Do not oppose me in the tribunal,
> Do not rebel against me before the guardian of the scales!
> You are my ka within my body,
> The Khnum who prospers my limbs.
> Go to the good place prepared for us,
> Do not make my name stink before them,
> The magistrates who put people in their places!
> If it's good for us it's good for the judge...

The idea of being so judged (and the fear of being found wanting) is not uncommon in one form or another across civilizations throughout history.

[image]

Comment: I didn't get that from OP, but... I would have to say he was the *judged* who had *fallen short*.

Answer (score 0):

Man was **convicted**(found guilty)/**acquitted**(not found guilty) by the court/jury/king.

Comment: This is not really normal for the "found wanting"-type of judgment.

Comment: @virmaior, Why not? http://thesaurus.com/browse/found+wanting

Comment: The thesaurus does not tell you what a word means. It tells you what words have similar meanings. There are legal judgments and judgments of character / performance. The words you are using refer to legal judgments. The question seems (at least on my reading) to be looking for judgments of character. For the latter , the convicted man makes no sense at all.

Comment: How is it a judgement of character? It simply says "The King judged the man, and the man was found wanting". 'John was brought before the king on the charges of robbery. The king looked at the evidence, asked questions and John was found wanting'.[John was convicted]

Answer (score 0):

"Judged" here means "assessed" or "evaluated". "Found wanting" means he wasn't up to scratch/didn't meet the standards.

So he was evaluated, but they didn't find him good enough.